# Addition of hidden values from 4 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to make a system in excel wherein if I put ‘yes’ against three columns out of four columns then the total(hidden cost) must be calculated only on the basis of three columns.
Now I also have to put some numerical values which will be the cost of the respective column but this should be hidden.**How to hide values**
Example if I have **hidden range** say 10 in col 1,15 in col 2,30 in col  3 and 20 in col 4 then 
if **I put ‘yes’ in col 1 col 2 col 3 and ‘no’ in col 4 then cost must come out to be 55.**
I am a beginner and struggling to work on it.Please advice.

Comment: Why don't you hide columns 1,3,5,and 7 and put YES in columns 2,4,6, and 8

Comment: Ok thanks,even this is better but how to add total cost when only three have yes and one has no in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the screenshot and imagine that the gray columns are hidden.  To keep things simple the formula that checks for yes has been split accross 4 columns that will also be hidden `=IF(B1="YES",A1,0)` `=IF(D1="YES",C1,0)` etc. The formula in I1 is a sum of those 4 hidden columns `=SUM(J1:M1)`

[image: Screenshot]

Simpler version

This version puts all the hidden columns together and the sum can be calculated using a single formula.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Thankyou so much..but is there any other way also for this.

Comment: Now that you mention it.  Yes, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..understood

Comment: Thanks for asking for a simpler way as I was trying to put the numbers and YESs next to each other and it's not easy to calculate that way.  If you're happy with the answer then you can mark it as accepted using the tick.Thanks.